# How do I declare and access arrays in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I declared an array of strings and initialized every element to "5". But when I debug with a breakpoint after the For-Each, all my array members have Nothing in them. I'm on Visual Studio 2010. Help please?

```
Dim words(999) As String

For Each word As String In words
    word = "5"
Next
```

Comment: This initializes nothing. The iterator returns a temporary string that contains the value of the item in the array. Since you've put nothing in there, there's nothing to get back. You might want to read [Arrays in VB.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) here to help you get started. I removed the extraneous tags like `microsoft`, `visual`, and `basic`, as `VB.NET` automatically means those things. `Visual Studio` is pretty much implied as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is good for reading array's, but not for writing them.  Your code translates to:

```
Create words array with 1000 elements
For each index in the array
    word = words(index)
    word = "5"
Next index
```

At no point does it put the word back into the array.  The code is missing:

```
    ...
    words(index) = word
Next index
```

What you need to do is:

```
Dim words(999) As String

For index As Integer = 0 to words.Length - 1
    words(index) = "5"
Next
```

**Edit:** In response to the comment below.

Once you've initialised the array, you can use a For/Each loop to read the elements.

```
For Each word As String in words
    Console.WriteLine(word)
Next
```

This is the same as:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To words.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine(words(index))
Next
```

Comment: Does this mean I can't/shouldn't use for-each for arrays?

Comment: You can't use For/Each for initialising arrays.  For/Each is only useful for reading arrays.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
Dim Words() As String = Enumerable.Repeat("5", 1000).ToArray()
```